# Reading a raw array stored in mysql with blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I have some data i have stored in mysql and it looks like this

```
["1109255736625955df9fbef.jpg","707361535625955dfa0564.jpg","1126563303625955dfa0c5c.jpg"]
```

i stored this data as an array in a field called `product_images` that holds strings.

Is there a way of iterating through this data without making it a php array at first but instead iterate it in blade straight from the database?.

This doesn't work

```
            <div class="row">
            @foreach ($product->product_images as $image)
            <div class="col-3">
            {{$image}}
            </div>
            @endforeach
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [mutators to cast array](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

Product in model add:

```
protected $casts = [
    'product_images' => 'array',
];
```

The cast from string to array is done under the hood for you

Answer (score 3):

Your data is stored in database as string, so you should transform it to array. Convenient way to do that is creating **[Cast](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)** in your model. Thanks this you transform data from this column to array on fetch and transforming to json when stored.

```
protected array $casts = [
    'product_images' => 'array'
]
```